# How to fetch user data from LDAP with Grails?

Tags: grails, ldap

I have a legacy Grails project that uses GormAuthorization. What I need to do is to make the app fetch some data from the LDAP server and store it in the DB.

I tried to use the `spring-security-ldap` plugin for that, but failed to make it work together with existing authorization method. Is there any convenient way to fetch LDAP data with Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find any suitable solution with Grails or groovy, so finally decided to stick to this Java library: https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/.